# downloading a large database

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I tried to export a large sized database using phpmyadmin but later the downloaded file seems to be of incorrect size, many of the tables inside the database are eliminated during download. The file size is about 700MB-1GB

In Export of phpmyadmin, i save the file as mydb.sql then in mysql I use "source" command to save it into mysql. The DB file is originally stored in another server (in another country). I access phpmyadmin with password and username. I guess now you understand my situation, I would like to get down this large db file then use it locally for test and development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much better to use mysqldump for exporting that large database.

You can do this with

`mysqldump -u username -p -h hostname --databases yourdatabase > yourfile.sql`

But you must have user that can connect from outside of server.

Perfect solution will be do this export localy on server then download it via ftp. But for this you need shell account.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I update to clearify better, I hope you could help me.

Comment: Thank you for your update, it works correctly now. I have used Putty and it also works as expected, the same as what you told me, except I didn't enter the hostname because I connect to the host server using Putty already. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

most probably you'd like to know how to export from mysql dataset that is more than few megabytes. web tools are not very well suited for that. if you have access to the shell on the server or remote access to mysql instance where the data is stored - try using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

if you dont have shell access you can try using phpmyadmin to dump table after table and there  select row ranges [how many rows per dump? that you'll have to find out empirically].

Comment: Thank, I finished it with the above method. I will try to dump table after table next time if I have another chance.